# My downloads hang across the OS

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I am using MacOs Sierra and downloads across the operating system hang after a few seconds. To successfully download a file, I have to pause and resume the download over and over until it completes. Here's what I have tried:

1. Changing browsers. **Didn't help**
2. Download accelerators. **Didn't help**
3. Switching from wifi to wired internet **Didn't help**
4. Switching to windows on the same computer **Worked**

Is there anything else that I should look into?

Answer (score 1):

The next thing is to determine if all network downloads are broken on your Mac or just Apple downloads.

It's possible you have a bad external network route or the networking settings on the Mac are substantially different than the PC. It could also be as simple as the date / time are wrong on the Mac or some other thing that is breaking SSL/HTTPS/TLS or whatever secure connection the Mac is negotiating with the download server.

Is there a reason you aren't using the App Store to do the download? Perhaps bad speeds or remote / heavily filtered internet in your country?

Comment: Yes, this applies to all downloads. Applies to App Store as well as browser downloads. It's a new installation with default configuration. Windows was installed just for troubleshooting and was on default configuration as well. I can access the internet (including app store on my iPhone) perfectly on my other devices.